# Opinion on whether to use a hash or an array, pushing new element in Rails

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

I'm working on a Rails 3 app where a user's profile `has_many :todos`. The user has three categories of `:todos`: two that are added to by clicking buttons on other pages, and one that they can add to themselves (through a status-update-like form).

So I'm interested in your thoughts on:

1. How to best set it up, particularly whether to use arrays or hashes. I'd like to count all of the `:todos` as well as list the string values for the individual categories.
2. The best way to push to the two categories that aren't like status updates. I'd attach the push to a button most likely, so the push would come on click or something.

**UPDATE:** Just to check...

The Profile Model:

```
has_many :todo, :through => :profiles_todos
has_many :profiles_todos
```

The ProfilesTodos Model:

```
belongs_to :profile
belongs_to :todo
```

And the `profiles_todos` Migration:

```
(in self.up)
  t.string :category 
  t.integer :profile_id 
  t.integer :todo_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend creating a join model UsersTo-dos that has a field category:string. This way the to-dos can be unique in the database, and shared between multiple users. Use `has_many :users_to-dos` along with `has_many :to-dos, :through => :users_to-dos` to make @user.to-dos an array of to-dos, and @user.users_to-dos an array of join objects with the category and the to-do object. You can then use the push method to add to the to-dos, or your can build new users_to-dos objects and add the category and to-do reference.

Comment: Just curious (I'm new to programming/Rails), but how would it look to build a new object and add the category? Say I have :to-dos (general) and :to-dos_groceries. Just define it in the Controller and make it @users_to-dos_groceries?

Comment: You don't want to have two models. Use the join table model to set the category. For example, say you have a method on User called `add_grocery_item(item)` this would do the following: `self.users_to-dos.build :category => 'grocery', :to-do_id => item.id` then when you reload that user from the database, it will have the new to-do item. To get all grocery items, you would run 
`@user.users_to-dos.select{|users_to_do| users_to_do.category == 'grocery'}.each do |users_to_do|
  to_do = users_to_do.to-do
  # code and manipulation here
end`

Comment: sorry the formatting is weird in comments. Also, I am not sure here, but I don't _think_ you can use hyphens in variable names. If it works for you, that's fine, but the best-practice ruby/rails way to name things is with underscores(_)

Comment: Gotcha, thanks! And +1 for best-practice way on underscores. I used that as an example but it's a good reminder!

Comment: I took your comments and added them to the end of the question for the sake of formatting. Does that look right or did I misinterpret?

Comment: No you are going to want to make add_grocery_item(item) a method on the model, because this is business logic. Also, you don't want the migration to occur on todos, that should be a new MODEL (`rails generate model profiles_todos category:string profile_id:integer todo_id:integer`) with a `belongs_to :profile; belongs_to :todo` on the model.

Comment: Where do I store the actual `item`? I see I have `category` strings, `profile_id`, and `todo_id`, but how do I store the actual `todo`?